# Count how many numbers appears in a string

Tags: php

I was wondering if there's a combo of functions or a direct function that can count how many numbers appears in a string, without use a long-way as `str_split` and check every character in a loop.

From a string like:

```
fdsji2092mds1039m
```

It returns that there's `8` numbers inside.

Comment: Please provide examples mentioning your input and expected output.

Comment: Yes, there is; have you looked for and tried something that may have failed you?

Comment: Use PHP strlen.

Comment: OP is looking for numbers in a string, not the length of the string @PhpDev

Comment: @ObjectManipulator I don't understand which example you want (I think that it's clear the question) however I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter_var()` with the `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` constant, then check the length of the new string. The new string will contain only numbers from that string, and all other characters are filtered away.

```
$string = "j3987snmj3j";
$numbers = filter_var($string , FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$length = strlen($numbers); // 5
echo "There are ".$length." numbers in that string";
```

Note that each number will be counted individually, so `137` would return `3`, as would `1m3j7`.

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/RFqEl)

Comment: `Remove all characters except digits, plus and minus sign.`. The result is wrong with this for instance`'fdsji2092mds1039m++'`

Answer (score 1):

Other solution:

```
function countNumbers(string $string) {
    return preg_match_all('/\d/', $string, $m);
}
```

You can use regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$myString = 'Som3 Charak1ers ar3 N0mberZ h3re ;)';
$countNumbers = strlen((string)filter_var($myString, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
echo 'Your input haz ' . $countNumbers . ' digits in it, man';
```

You can also make a function out of this to return only the number, if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Following code does what you intend to do:

```
<?php
$string = 'dsfds98fsdfsdf8sdf908f9dsf809fsd809f8s15d0d';
$splits=str_split($string);
$count=0;
foreach ($splits as $split){
    if(is_numeric($split)){
        $count++;
    }
}

print_r($count);
```

Output: `17`